# What is the best way to feed IMU data to CNN?

Tags: predictive-models, multivariate-analysis, conv-neural-network, tensorflow, convolution

I took the [Introduction to Embedded Machine Learning](https://www.coursera.org/?skipBrowseRedirect=true) course, which is provided by Shawn Hymel, on Coursera. While talking about sensor fusion, he made the following statement for the following diagram:

[image: Sensor Fusion schema]

> In this example, you might need to calculate the quaternions from the
> sensors first before feeding them to the model. Then the neural
> network can be used to make a decision or classification, about what
> to do with that absolute orientation.

Then, I had a look at *quaternions*. There is [nice video on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zjMuIxRvygQ) which explains, what they are, how they work. We basically use them to represent 3D-rotation. However, I am confused how can I apply this to my data (or should I?).

I will be using [Arduino Nano 33 BLE Sense](https://store-usa.arduino.cc/products/arduino-nano-33-ble-sense) to detect anomalies on robotic arm. An example data are:

```
Accelerometer: [1.44, -0.02, 0.99] Gyroscope: [-1.40, 0.49, -0.67] Magnetometer: [60.21, 21.18, -61.55].
```

I will be feeding IMU data to 1D-CNN, as there are several research([1](https://dl.acm.org/doi/abs/10.1145/3264888.3264896?casa_token=eqqe0qvBOT8AAAAA:TSfOaUjvCQWzKHnAn54Z9boUInDmTfR6kH8ubsI_0CB179Sv0XuC1zWaR2JUScCdzymTZsBzKUXW), [2](https://www.mdpi.com/2227-9709/7/4/49)) that shows 1D-CNN works well with time-series data. I am using [TensorFlow Lite for Micro](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/microcontrollers), hence there are [limited operations available.](https://github.com/tensorflow/tflite-micro/blob/main/tensorflow/lite/micro/all_ops_resolver.cc) There is no 1D-Convolution function, but we can simulate them via using 2D-Convolution function as stated by Pete Warden in [GitHub discussion:](https://github.com/tensorflow/tflite-micro/issues/149)

> we recommend using Conv2D with a 1xSize kernel shape instead of
> Conv1D.

Initially, I was thinking to feed raw IMU data to per sensor per dimension to CNN, then combine the results, to predict each data point. But, I am confused after taking that course. How should I proceed to get best results?

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways of representing a 3D rotation as some vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$. However, many of these representations have the disadvantage that arbitrarily small rotations / change in rotation can lead to large differences the vector representation. For example, with euler angles, a small movement near the poles might be represented as a 180-degree rotation on one of the axes. In general, this is undesireable because it is hard for neural networks to learn "discontinuous" things, and easy for neural networks to learn "nicely behaved" things. Quanternions are one representation of rotations which don't suffer from this behavior, so they are a suitable input to neural nets.